# Can ionized air be used as a conductive medium for eddy brakes?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction, plasma-physics

Sort of a conceptual engineering question, apologies if I am missing something, my background is in mechanical engr.

Essentially, I was inspired by the classic experiment of dropping a magnet in a copper tube.

As far as I understand, the slowing of the magnet is due to the presence of eddy currents forming in the copper tube and providing a retardant force to the magnet.

Lets say that instead of copper, this tube was replaced with ionized air, or an otherwise low temperature plasma that had a somewhat laminar flow through an annular channel, basically creating a tube where the walls are made of ionized gas rather than copper.

When I drop a magnet through this “tube”, would it experience eddy current braking like it would falling down a copper tube?
Would the conductive gas behave like a conducting metal? Beyond complicated flow dynamics, am I missing some fundamental physics?

Comment: Don't maglev trains rely, in some part, on this principle?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a good one, and has been a subject of research for a number of years in the field of *magnetohydrodynamics*, or MHD (convenient search term). This is a frightfully complicated field because it mixes electromagnetism, fluid dynamics, and thermodynamics together into a hot mess.